# Обновление счетчика просмотров Angular + Firebase

Tags: angular2, typescript, firebase

Всем привет. Я пытаюсь сделать счетчик просмотров статьи используя Angular + Firebase. Вот так выглядит модель статьи:

```
id?: string;
title: string;
text: string;
views: number;
```

Количество просмотров хранится в поле `views`. Нужно увеличивать количество просмотров каждый раз при открытии статьи. Моя реализация:

**article.component.ts**

```
export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  article: Article;

  constructor( 
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private articleService: ArticleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let articleId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.getArticle(articleId);
  }

  getArticle(id: string) {
    this.articleService.getById(id).subscribe(article => {
      this.article = article;
      ++this.article.views;
      this.title.setTitle(this.article.title);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.articleService.update(this.article);
  }
}
```

**article.service.ts**

```
export class ArticleService {
  getById(id: string): Observable<Article> {
    return this.db.doc('articles/' + id)
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(doc => {
        return {
          id: doc.payload.id,
          ...doc.payload.data()
        } as Article;
      }));
  }

  update(article: Article) {
    this.db.doc('articles/' + article.id).update(article);
  }
}
```

Проблема данной реализации в том, что если пользователь откроет статью по ссылке и потом закроет браузер, то `ngOnDestroy` не сработает и просмотры не обновятся.

Я пытался сделать обновление просмотров при получении статьи в `subscribe`, однако там случается бесконечный инкремент счетчика.

**Как правильно сделать обновление просмотров?**

Comment: а зачем обновлять счетчик в ondestroy а не в конструкторе? оО

Comment: > `там случается бесконечный инкремент счетчика` - потому что ты используешь `snapshotChanges` - обновил счетчик, сокет тригернулся, `snapshotChanges` сгенерил событие и вызвал колбек где обновляется счетчик, обновил счетчик, сокет тригернулся, вот тебе и бесконечный цикл

Comment: в предыдущем твоем вопросе я тебе написал как избежать бесконечного цикла, ты проигнорировал. Как говорится - шо маемо то маемо :D

Comment: @overthesanity спасибо за ответ. я пропустил ваш комментарий в предыдущем вопросе. Он действительно помог решить мою проблему